# How t return a json response in GET request?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

Looking for some help as i am new to python and django ,I am trying to return a response in JSON of an API GET request as the data is to be returned is dictionary made from different instances of different model. but few things are not getting converted in JSON like datetime amount in decimal throwing an error saying not serializable.Also how can i get all the transfer for that perticular order in a list and each instance in a dictionary like[{},{}]

```
views.py
@api_view(['GET'])
def details(request,id):
    if request.method=='GET':
        order = get_object_or_404(Orders,id=id,applications=application)
        collection = get_object_or_404(Payments,orders=id,direction='COLLECTION',is_active=True) 
        transfer = get_object_or_404(Payments,orders=order,direction='TRANSEFER',is_active=True)
        content =  {
                    'orders': {
                        "id":id,
                        "purpose_code":order.purpose_code,
                        "amount":order.amount,
                        'collection_payments':{
                            "id":collection_payments.id,
                            "amount":collection_payments.amount,
                            "datetime":collection_payments.datetime,
                            'transfer': [
                                     {
                                         "id":transfer.id,
                                         "amount":transfer.amount,
                                        "datetime":transfer.datetime,
                                     }    
                                ]
                            }
                       }
                    }
        return Response(content, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

models.py
class Orders(models.Model):
    id= models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    applications = models.ForeignKey(Applications, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=4)



 class Payments(models.Model):
        id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
        orders = models.ForeignKey(Orders, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        direction = models.CharField(max_length=20,choices=[('COLLECTION','COLLECTION'), 
                                                           ('TRANSFER','TRANSFER')])
        amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=4, verbose_name='Price in INR')
        datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False,auto_now_add=False)
        is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

Comment: Use a [Serializer (DRF docs)](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat won't return JsonResponse(content) work ? or it is necessary to use serializers ?

Comment: Yes that will also work, but then what's the point of you using DRF anyway, if you are manually going to serialize each instance?